# UpdateSingleSalesforceObject - Error in the application

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to save the send date in a Sales Cloud field with this expression:

```
%%[SET @Lead_Id="00Q3100000Z3HIcAAN", SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead',@Lead_Id,'Reminder_Email1_Sent__c',Now())]%%
```

This results in an error.

> Call to update the salesforceobject Lead ID = 00Q3100000Z3HIcAAN failed! Error in the application.

Has anybody an idea why?

The field '`Reminder_Email1_Sent__c`' is a date field on a Lead Object.

Comment: what error you getting

Comment: Do you  have  a integration between salesforce to salesforce marketing cloud?

Comment: Error is outlined above.

>> Call to update the salesforceobject Lead ID = 00Q3100000Z3HIcAAN failed! Error in the application.<<

Yeah it is integrated and other updates are working well in the same email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be due to different reasons, but guess would be that the date time format generated by the `Now()` function is not in the same syntax that is required by the date field in Sales Cloud.

I would try formatting the date as follows:

```js
%%[
var @Lead_Id, @result, @dateTime

set @dateTime = Replace(FormatDate(Now(),"yyyy-MM-ddT","hh:mm:ss"),' ','')
set @Lead_Id = "00Q3100000Z3HIcAAN"
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead',@Lead_Id,'Reminder_Email1_Sent__c',@dateTime)
]%%
```

Comment: how should this be done for a Date field? (not datetime) @Eliot Harper

Answer (score 1):

@Alexander Schmelzer first check integration is there or not if integrated mean try like this

```
%%[
    var @result
    SET @Lead_Id="00Q3100000Z3HIcAAN"

    SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead',@Lead_Id,'Reminder_Email1_Sent__c',Format(Now(),"yyyy-MM-dd"))
      ]%%
```

Comment: This answer may work, but the timestamp will be stripped. I'd suggest trying my answer first.

Comment: @pkharries, thank you for your answer, unfortunately, it did now work. I got the same error like before.